# Android - Custom annotation TargetFlavor like TargetApi but for flavors

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations, kotlin

I'm currently working to create a custom annotation which does the same work as `@TargetApi()` but with my flavors.

### **The Case**

In my case, I need to use a certain method (in a class called `Navigator`) to redirect my application to another screen but I create this screen only in one of the flavors. So when I switch to another Build Variant, my Android Studio display an error: `Unresolved reference`, as expected.

I have 3 flavors: `device1`, `device2` and `device3`. Also `device1` has this unique screen (called `UniqueActivity`) and all flavors have access to `Navigator` class.

I see the use case like this:

```
@TargetFlavor(currentFlavor = BuildConfig.FLAVOR, targetFlavor = "device1")
```

### **The (almost perfect) solution**

So I thought about preprocessor annotation to ignore method when the selected flavor (by the Build Variant) does not correspond to the target flavor. I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@iammert/annotation-processing-dont-repeat-yourself-generate-your-code-8425e60c6657).

And here is what I achieved:

**TargetFlavor annotation:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TargetFlavor {
    String currentFlavor();
    String targetFlavor();
}
```

**TargetFlavorProcessor:**

```
public class TargetFlavorProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Filer filer;
    private Messager messager;
    private Elements elements;
    private Map<String, Boolean> methodWithFlavor;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);

        filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
        messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        elements = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
        methodWithFlavor = new HashMap<>();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {

        for (Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TargetFlavor.class)) {

            if (element.getKind() != ElementKind.METHOD) {
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Must be applied on methods");
                return true;
            }

            TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) element;
            TargetFlavor annotation = element.getAnnotation(TargetFlavor.class);
            methodWithFlavor.put(
                    typeElement.getSimpleName().toString(),
                    annotation.targetFlavor().equals(annotation.currentFlavor()));
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> methods : methodWithFlavor.entrySet()) {

            if (!methods.getValue()) {

                // Here, I want the compiler to ignore method which not correspond

            }

        }

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(TargetFlavor.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {return SourceVersion.latest();}

}
```

But I'm stuck when I want to force my compiler to ignore certain methods selected by `@TargetFlavor()`.

Is there a better way to do this, or am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I tried to implement the annotation for flavors using a similar approach. Now I am stuck and can't figure out how to let compiler know whether to ignore or include a particular method. If you figured out a way for this then please let me know.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder For my old project when I had needed this approach, I found something else like duplicate files for each flavor I had. Sorry, I did not try again to finish this way.

Comment: Yeah I'll be doing the same. Thanks!